# Update after fetch stops and promise isn't resolved in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch, setstate

I'm trying to build some sort of coin collector and an on button click function fires a fetch request to the db updating the number by one. Right now the new number is only shown after refreshing the page. I intend to have the component rerendered after the fetch function has put the new value. But in my code the promises after the fetch function are never reached therefore  the update is always fired before the fetch is done. I also thought of updating the state of the item, but as there are multiple cards created by a map function, I can't change the state of an individual card.

So this is the function where I render my semantic cards and where updateNumber is called.

```
  renderCards = ({ idCollection, countryName, Year, SpecialCoins, name, existing, number, circulating, commemorative, edition, coinImage }) =>
<div className="card">
  <div className="image">
    <img alt={coinImage} src={"http://localhost:3000/images/" + coinImage + ".png"} />
  </div>
  <div className="content">
    <button onClick={(e) => this.updateNumber(e, idCollection, number)} className="circular ui icon button">{number}</button>
    <div className="ui sub header" key={Year} countryName={countryName} year={Year}>{Year + " " + name + " " + countryName}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="extra content">
    <span className="right floated">Auflage: {edition}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

So this is the updateNumber function

```
    updateNumber(e,idCollection,number){

    var data={
    idCollection:idCollection,
    number:number + 1
      }
      update(data);
      function update(data) {

      fetch('http://localhost:3001/all/update', {
          method: 'put',
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        }) //From here on the promises are never reached
          .then(checkStatus)
          .then(()=>console.log('updated!!!'))

      }

      function checkStatus(response) {
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {

          return response
        } else {
          var error = new Error(response.statusText)
          error.response = response
          throw error
        }
      }
    }
```

And lastly this is the code I get my data from

```
   state = {
    all: []
  }

componentWillMount(){
    this.getAll();
} 

  getAll(){
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/all")
    .then(response => response.json())
   .then(response => {
     console.log(response)
      this.setState({
        all: response.all
      })
    })
    .then(response => this.setState({all: response.response}))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    }
```

I haven't come up with a solution for this for multiple hours now and I hope that someone knows what I messed up and can help. Thanks!

Comment: are you saying `console.log('updated!!!')` never happens? perhaps `response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300` is false?

Comment: perhaps function `updateNumber` and/or `update` need to return a promise for your code to be functional?

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter too early. When I do .then(console.log("something") something is printed out on the console. but whenever i put a function there it will not give an error but not performing the function either.

Comment: so, `console.log` gets run, but nothing else you put there does? I don't believe that at all

Comment: I tried making a new function writeline(){console.log("sth")} and after the fetch i did .then(()=>this.writeline()) but the console log within the writeline function doesn't show up but when I do it directly in the .then(console.log("sth")) It works.

Comment: `.then(this.writeline())` - because `.then` expects a **function** as an argument, whereas you calling a function as an argument

Comment: I tried an arrow function as well, same result like .then(()=>this.writeline()) am I missing out on something?